# Handling errors for broken JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, exception

If the element `#the-json` is empty it will cause this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

For the following code:

```
myJSON = JSON.parse($("#the-json").attr('value'));
```

How should this error be handled so it doesn't stop the entire script working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use try-catch statement:

```
try {
  myJSON = JSON.parse($("#the-json").attr('value'));
} catch (e) {
  // handle error
}
```

Or check before do something:

```
var myJSON = JSON.parse('{}'); // default value

if ($("#the-json").attr('value')) {
  myJSON = JSON.parse($("#the-json").attr('value'));
}
```

Comment: Is it good practice to just wrap all javascript in try catch?

Comment: @ami - not ALL the code... just the parts that you can predict possible problems.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than catching errors when they happen - **prevent errors from happening in the first place!**  Simply test the value attribute and if its empty - explicitly specify that it is.  Then your JSON parser will not complain - it'll just create an empty object.

You can simply test for empty content and provide an empty object -

```
var data = $("#the-json").attr('value') == ''? '{}': $("#the-json").attr('value');
myJSON = JSON.parse(data);
if ($.isEmptyObject(myJSON)){
  // there was no value
}
```

The `{}` syntax implies an empty JavaScript object.